# Trying to parse out only 1 thing from every line

Tags: for-loop, batch-file

When I try to parse string I get data after it I don't want.
Trying to get only first item after first space in every row i.e., in row 1 only want LP23044 so I can copy files.

Note: After 1st number in each line and period there is a space.

1. LP23044  3/24/2023 12:00:00 AM
2. BUG_HCNA_LIVE    3/24/2023 12:00:00 AM
3. BUG_HCNA1    3/24/2023 12:00:00 AM
4. PR35878  3/24/2023 12:28:45 AM
5. PR26662  3/24/2023 12:29:15 AM
6. UPNEXTHC 3/24/2023 12:29:52 AM
7. UPNEXT_DSK.oaseq 3/24/2023 12:29:52 AM
8. PR3501   3/24/2023 12:59:36 AM
9. PR22204CF    3/24/2023 1:28:00 AM
10. PRIDGNT2301 3/24/2023 1:28:45 AM
11. BHD2305012  3/24/2023 1:30:40 AM
12. PR7760  3/24/2023 1:44:14 AM
13. PR8858  3/24/2023 1:59:26 AM
14. HC0001858   3/24/2023 2:00:00 AM

FOR /f "tokens=2 delims=" %%G in (missingfiles.txt) DO robocopy -j M:\ F:\Media\ %%G.*

Expected after first 2 token I get only filename.

Comment: Try `FOR /f %%G in (missingfiles.txt) DO robocopy -j M:\ F:\Media\ %%G.*`, that is, the _first_ token delimited by space or TAB...

Comment: Is the number followed by the period and the space actually part of the text file contents? The entire question hinges on whether or not that's the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After meany tries I figured out removing delims=" addressed my need.

for /f "tokens=2" %%G in (missingfiles.txt) do robocopy -j M:\ F:\Media %%G.*

Comment: This "solution" just gets _the date_ in each line... The solution is `FOR /f %%G in (missingfiles.txt) DO robocopy -j M:\ F:\Media\ %%G.*` as I said before...

Comment: This is just my answer. If I solved your problem, please click the check mark next to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

`"tokens=2 delims="` means "treat the entire line as a single item, and return the second item" so there is nothing to return. If you simply remove the `delims=`, your loop will work as intended.

```
for /f "tokens=2" %%G in (missingfiles.txt) do robocopy -j M:\ F:\Media %%G.*
```